# XMLHttpRequest not working - no errors

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get this simple request working but I am not having much luck.
I have the "test.txt" file in the server folder as my html file containing the script provided below.

I viewed the file in Chrome, Firefox and IE11 with the same result. I can only see the "Initial text in the html page.." text from the html page. No errors and the text from my test.txt file is not getting displayed.

Could anyone please point me what the issue with my code is?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();

    function createXmlHttpRequestObject(){

        var xmlHttp

        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){      
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else{           
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        return xmlHttp:
    }   

    function process(){

        if(xmlHttp){
            try{                
                xmlHttp.open("GET","test.txt", true);               
                xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;              
                xmlHttp.send(null);
            }
            catch(e){
                alert( e.toString() );
            }
        }
    }

    function handleServerResponse(){        

        output = document.getElementById('output');

        if(xmlHttp.readyState==1){
            output.innerHTML += "Status 1: server connection established <br />" 
        }
        else if(xmlHttp.readyState==2){
            output.innerHTML += "Status 2: request received <br />"     
        }
        else if(xmlHttp.readyState==3){
            output.innerHTML += "Status 3: server processing <br />"    
        }
        else(xmlHttp.readyState==4){ 

                if(xmlHttp.status=200){
                    try{
                        text = xmlHttp.responseText;
                        output.innerHTML += "Status 4: request is finished and response is ready<br />" 
                        output.innerHTML += text;
                    }
                    catch(e){ 
                        alert( e.toString() );
                    }
                }
                else{
                    alert( xmlHttp.statusText );
                }
        }
    }

    </script>
</head>

<body onload="process()">
    Initial text in the html page..<br>
    <br>

    <div id="output">
    </div>

</body>



</html>
```

Comment: Two things, make sure you preface your variable declarations with `var` and secondly have you tried setting breakpoints in the browser's debugger? In chrome just hold shift-cntrl-i to pull up the dev tools

Comment: @Jared Smith - thanks for the tip. I got to the bottom of it and posting a resolution as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out....

it was one typo and one ommision

```
return xmlHttp: -> should  be ; instead
```

and forgot "else"

```
else(xmlHttp.readyState==4){ -> should be else if (xmlHttp.readyState==4){
```